# Android res/layout Folder not included in the APK file (but included in the ANE)

Tags: android, air, android-resources, air-native-extension

I'm having a problem with resources on an Adobe ANE Android extension:

> android.content.res.Resources@NotFoundException:  id.myView

I have a xml layout file, which is included in the ANE file (checking by unzipping the ANE file and looking into `META-INF/ANE/Android-ARM`)

In the APK file (generated with Flash Builder 4.6), the `layout` folder (inside `res`) at the top level is missing, but it's included deep in the `assets` folder:

```
- META-INF    
- res
    drawable
    drawable-hdpi
    drawable-ldpi
    drawable-mdpi
    raw
- assets
    META-INF
        AIR
            extensions
                org.dornad.ane.MyTestExtension
                    META-INF
                        ANE
                            Android-ARM
                                    drawable-hdpi
                                    drawable-mdpi
                                    drawable-xhdpi
                                    layout
                                    values
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in my apks, the drawable, drawable-hdpi folders are in *within* the res folder, I don't understand how they could be present without the res folder.  Are these drawable, etc folders at the root of the apk?

Comment: You are correct, the "layout" folder is the missing one.  And actually, both "layout" and "values" folders in res are missing.  I'll update the question with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:  It was a problem in the Ant Script used to Compile the ANE.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your initial problem and solution in a little more detail?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem (res included in .ane but not in apk) so it indeed could have been very useful for others to share your solution details with them ...