# Unclickable Items under WebView

Tags: java, android, air, air-native-extension

I'm have this test app in Adobe AIR using an Android ANE to insert a VideoView to watch a video.  The problem is that once the video is added, the rest of the screen is not clickable.

Here is the code used to insert the VideoView:

```
// File:  VideoPlayerTestActivity.java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);  // always call this

    VideoView videoHolder = new VideoHolder(this);
    this.programaticallyAddToLayout(videoHolder);

    // Add the media controllers at bottom of video, instead of screen bottom
    videoHolder.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                    MediaController mc = new MediaController(VideoPlayerTestActivity.this);
                    videoHolder.setMediaController(mc);
                    mc.setAnchorView(videoHolder);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoHolder.setVideoURI( Uri.parse(mediaURL) );
    videoHolder.requestFocus();
    videoHolder.start();
}
```

And here is the code for method programaticallyAddToLayout(), which creates the layout that should be in the XML.  (I'm not using the xml layout file, for some reason which still eludes me, [the app cannot find the xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187223/)):

```
private void programaticallyAddToLayout( VideoView videoView ) 
{
    FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(800, 600);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    layout.setId(1);
    layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    videoView.setId(2);
    layout.addView( videoView, layoutParams );
    this.setContentView( layout );
}
```

Here is a screengrab of the app, for reference:

[image: screengrab]

Comment: which part that you want to make it click?
did you want something like thatbutton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {...}); ?

Answer (score 0):

Put a background on the video view of say red for testing. The video or layout may be covering your button and if clickable=true then the events wont propagate past that lay and hit the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind for how to fix this. First, why are you calling `requestFocus()` on the `VideoView`? This may have adverse effects.

If this puts your `VideoView` behind your other views, you can move it to the front as follows:

```
videoview.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Android 2.1 and 2.2 but not when i port to 2.3